# If query returns one or more rows, return the row/rows and exit

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three statements. If any of them returns *anything* I want that to be returned and the query to exit.

```
select * 
from   connexion
where  origin = 'Stockholm'
and    destination = 'Berlin';
-- IF IT RETURNS ONE OR MORE ROWS THEN RETURN ROW/ROWS AND EXIT, ELSE GO TO STATEMENT BELOW

select * 
from   connexion c1, connexion c2
where  c1.origin = 'Stockholm'
and    c2.destination = 'Berlin'
and    c1.destination = c2.origin;
-- IF IT RETURNS ONE OR MORE ROWS THEN RETURN ROW/ROWS AND EXIT, ELSE GO TO STATEMENT BELOW

select * 
from   connexion c1, connexion c2, connexion c3
where  c1.origin = 'Stockholm'
and    c3.destination = 'Berlin'
and    c1.destination = c2.origin
and    c2.destination = c3.origin;
-- IF IT RETURNS ONE OR MORE ROWS THEN RETURN ROW/ROWS AND EXIT, ELSE EXIT
```

Here's the query to create the database. I want to retrieve a result where I can go from Stockholm to Berlin via any of the available connexions.

```
create table busstop(
    city varchar(50),
    country varchar(50) not null,
    streetAddress varchar(50) not null,
    primary key (city)
);
```

create table driver(
    driverPnr varchar(13),
    name varchar(50) not null,
    address varchar(50) not null,
    phone varchar(12) not null,
    primary key (driverPnr)
);

create table customer(
    customerPnr varchar(13),
    name varchar(50) not null,
    email varchar(50) not null,
    phone varchar(12) not null,
    primary key (customerPnr)
);

create table connexion(
    connexionId serial not null,
    origin varchar(50) not null,
    destination varchar(50) not null,
    primary key (connexionId),
    foreign key (origin) references busstop(city),
    foreign key (destination) references busstop(city)
);

create table trip(
    tripId serial not null,
    connexionId integer not null,
    departure timestamp not null,
    arrival timestamp not null,
    driverPnr varchar(13),
    priceAmount integer not null,
    seats integer not null,
    primary key (tripId),
    foreign key (connexionId) references connexion(connexionId),
    foreign key (driverPnr) references driver(driverPnr)
);

create table booking(
    customerPnr varchar(13) not null,
    tripId integer not null,
    seats integer not null,
    primary key (customerPnr, tripId),
    foreign key (customerPnr) references customer(customerPnr),
    foreign key (tripId) references trip(tripId)
);

insert into busstop(city, country, streetAddress) values
    ('Stockholm', 'Sweden', 'Byvägen 1'),
    ('Copenhagen', 'Denmark', 'Vesterbrogade 23'),
    ('Berlin', 'Germany', 'Europaplatz 4'),
    ('Amsterdam', 'Netherlands', 'Stationsplein 17'),
    ('Prague', 'Czech Republic', 'Wilsonova 10');

insert into connexion(origin, destination) values
    ('Stockholm', 'Copenhagen'),
    ('Copenhagen', 'Stockholm'),

```
('Copenhagen', 'Berlin'),
('Berlin', 'Copenhagen'),

('Copenhagen', 'Amsterdam'),
('Amsterdam', 'Copenhagen'),

('Berlin', 'Prague'),
('Prague', 'Berlin'),

('Amsterdam', 'Berlin'),
('Berlin', 'Amsterdam'),

('Amsterdam', 'Prague'),
('Prague', 'Amsterdam');
```

insert into trip(connexionId, departure, arrival, priceAmount, seats) values
    -- Exits on 2018-04-21

```
    -- Stockholm - Copenhagen / Copenhagen - Stockholm, 3 hours
    (1, '2018-04-22 07:00:00', '2018-04-22 10:00:00', 200, 35),
    (2, '2018-04-22 18:00:00', '2018-04-22 21:00:00', 200, 35),

    -- Copenhagen - Berlin / Berlin - Copenhagen, 7 hours
    (3, '2018-04-22 10:00:00', '2018-04-22 17:00:00', 500, 35),
    (4, '2018-04-22 11:00:00', '2018-04-22 18:00:00', 500, 35),

    -- Copenhagen - Amsterdam / Amsterdam - Copenhagen, 9 hours
    (5, '2018-04-22 10:00:00', '2018-04-22 19:00:00', 800, 35),
    (6, '2018-04-22 09:00:00', '2018-04-22 18:00:00', 800, 35),

    -- Berlin - Prague / Prague - Berlin, 4 hours
    (7, '2018-04-22 17:00:00', '2018-04-22 21:00:00', 300, 35),  
    (8, '2018-04-22 07:00:00', '2018-04-22 11:00:00', 300, 35),

    -- Amsterdam - Berlin / Berlin - Amsterdam, 7 hours
    (9, '2018-04-22 07:00:00', '2018-04-22 14:00:00', 500, 35),
    (10, '2018-04-22 14:00:00', '2018-04-22 21:00:00', 500, 35),

    -- Amsterdam - Prague / Prague - Amsterdam, 9 hours
    (11, '2018-04-22 05:00:00', '2018-04-22 14:00:00', 800, 35),
    (12, '2018-04-22 14:00:00', '2018-04-22 23:00:00', 800, 35);
```

If I go from Stockholm to Berlin the query has to first check if there are any direct connexions between Stockholm and Berlin. If no, then it has to check if there are any connexion with ONE stopover, if so retrieve a row for that. If there's none, proceed with checking if there's any connexion with TWO stopovers, and it continues until it has checked THREE stopovers. (no one would want to travel from Stockholm to Berlin with more than three stopovers..).. It's so hard to explain what I want to achieve but I hope you get the point :)

Comment: Is it a function?

Comment: I use SQL Server all the time, and for such a case I'd use `@@rowcount`. Looks like you can use [`found`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS) keyword

Comment: Im not sure. As you maybe could guess the query search for a trip, either directly or with stopovers from an origin (Stockholm) to a destination (Berlin). If it fails to find a direct trip it has to look for stopovers between the origin and the destination. I need to try for atleast three stopovers. So basically I want it to try the first one, if there's nothing, proceed with the next one and so on..

Comment: I think a recusive CTE is the way to do this but I don't know if it is supported in postgresql

Comment: According to the docs is does support recursive.  That is the way to go.  You should post some data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

a reach and this is tsql
this is just direct or 1 stop

```
select 'Stockholm' as origin_, 'Berlin' as  destination_, *
from connexion c1 
join connexion c2
  on c1.origin = 'Stockholm'
 and (      c1.destination =  'Berlin'
        or (c1.destination <> 'Berlin' and c2.destination = 'Berlin') 
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with multiple joins:

```
select c1.*, c2.*, c3.*
from connexion c1 left join
     connexion c2
     on c1.origin = 'Stockholm' and
        (c1.destination =  'Berlin' or
         (c1.destination <> 'Berlin' and c2.destination = 'Berlin') 
        ) left join
     connection c3
     on c2.destination = c3.destination and
        (c2.destination <> 'Berlin' and
         c1.destination <> 'Berlin'
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is sql server but according to the docs postgresql supports recursion.

Stop is just the last stop.  This does not show you all stops.  Cnt is the number of stops.

```
declare @t table (orig varchar(20), dest varchar(20)
                  , primary key (orig, dest));
insert into @t values
   ('Stockholm',  'Copenhagen'),
   ('Copenhagen', 'Stockholm'),
   ('Copenhagen', 'Berlin'),
   ('Berlin',     'Copenhagen'),
   ('Copenhagen', 'Amsterdam'),
   ('Amsterdam',  'Copenhagen'),
   ('Berlin',     'Prague'),
   ('Prague',     'Berlin'),
   ('Amsterdam',  'Berlin'),
   ('Berlin',     'Amsterdam'),
   ('Amsterdam',  'Prague'),
   ('Prague',     'Amsterdam');
with cte as 
( select t.orig, t.orig as 'stop', t.dest, 1 as cnt 
  from @t t 
  union all 
  select cte.orig, t.orig, t.dest, cnt + 1 
  from @t t 
  join cte 
    on cte.dest = t.orig 
   and t.dest <> cte.orig  --don't loop back home
   and cnt < 4
)
select * 
 from cte 
where orig = 'Stockholm' 
  and dest = 'Berlin'
order by cnt, cte.stop
```

This will not prevent looping in route. By limiting cnt the loops are eliminated.  It prevents going back to the original city.

Answer (score -1):

You can use GOTo Statement in SQL . In below code you can assign your query counts and then in if condition you can count if its grater than 0 then GOTO respective query.

```
DECLARE @a  Int
DECLARE @b  Int
SELECT  @a  =   10
SELECT  @b  =   5
BEGIN
    IF      @a>@0 GOTO  Greater
    IF      @b>0 GOTO   Lesser
END
Greater:    SELECT  @a
Lesser:     SELECT  @b
```

Comment: SQL has no `GOTO` and neither has Postgres

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/goto-transact-sql    @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: That's T-SQL, not "SQL" (and the question is tagged with Postgres, not SQL Server)